# How Do I Properly Set --kubelet-certificate-authority apiserver parameter?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kube-apiserver

I am using **KubeSpray** to provision a two node cluster on AWS. By default, the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` parameter is not used. However, I would like to set it.

I do not know the correct setting for `--kubelet-certificate-authority`. When I set it to `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt` I see messages like the following in my logs:

```
TLS handshake error from 10.245.207.223:59278: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority
```

In order to create an isolated environment for testing, I SSH'ed to my controller node to run this command which runs apiserver on the non-standard port of `4667`. I copied these values directly from `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. You'll need to adjust the value to match your own cluster. I purposely am running the container in interactive mode so that I can see the log messages.

```sh
sudo docker run \
  --name api-server-playground \
  -it \
  --rm \
  --network host \
  --volume /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes:ro \
  --volume /etc/pki:/etc/pki:ro \
  --volume /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl/:ro \
  k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.18.9 \
  kube-apiserver \
    --advertise-address=10.245.207.223 \
    --allow-privileged=true \
    --anonymous-auth=True \
    --apiserver-count=1 \
    --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC \
    --bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
    --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt \
    --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud_config \
    --cloud-provider=aws \
    --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction \
    --enable-aggregator-routing=False \
    --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true \
    --endpoint-reconciler-type=lease \
    --etcd-cafile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem \
    --etcd-certfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-ip-10-245-207-223.ec2.internal.pem \
    --etcd-keyfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-ip-10-245-207-223.ec2.internal-key.pem \
    --etcd-servers=https://10.245.207.119:2379 \
    --event-ttl=1h0m0s \
    --insecure-port=0 \
    --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt \
    --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.key \
    --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalDNS,InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP \
    --profiling=False \
    --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.crt \
    --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.key \
    --request-timeout=1m0s \
    --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client \
    --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-ca.crt \
    --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- \
    --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group \
    --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User \
    --secure-port=6447 \
    --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/sa.pub \
    --service-cluster-ip-range=10.233.0.0/18 \
    --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 \
    --storage-backend=etcd3 \
    --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.crt \
    --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.key
```

Now it's possible to SSH into the controller again and use `curl` to interact with the custom apiserver container.

- Set the APISERVER variable to point to the controller node. I'm using the value of the `advertise-address` parameter above.

```
APISERVER=https://10.245.207.223:6447
```

- Get a token.

```sh
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secrets -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations['kubernetes\.io/service-account\.name']=='default')].data.token}"|base64 --decode); echo "TOKEN=$TOKEN"
```

- Make an api request. This request will fail because "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.".

```sh
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET $APISERVER/api
```

An error message will appear in the docker log. It will look like this:

```
I0921 14:39:07.662368       1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error 
from 10.245.207.223:59278: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority
```

- Now use the `-k` curl parameter to bypass the recognition issue.

```
curl -k --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET $APISERVER/api
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.245.207.223:6447"
    }
  ]
}
```

You'll see the request works correctly. However, I don't want to use the `-k` parameter. So I tried to use the certificate authority from the apiserver.

- Get the certificate authority from the apiserver.

```sh
echo | \
    openssl s_client -connect $APISERVER 2>/dev/null | \
    openssl x509 -text | \
    sed -n "/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p" \
    > apiserver.ca.crt
```

- Use the certificate authority file for the api request.

```sh
curl --cacert apiserver.ca.crt --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET $APISERVER/api
```

**UPDATE**

Following a thought prompted by Wiktor's response, I added /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt as the certificate authority. And used that file in my `curl` command.

```sh
curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET $APISERVER/api
```

This worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` flag work you first need to make sure you got [Kubelet authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authentication) and [Kubelet authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization) enabled. After that you can follow the Kubernetes documentation and setup the [TLS connection between the apiserver and kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#apiserver-to-kubelet). And finally, you can edit the API server pod specification file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on the master node and set the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` parameter to the path to the cert file for the certificate authority.

So, to sum up the steps to do are:

1. [Kubelet authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authentication):

- start the kubelet with the `--anonymous-auth=false` flag
- start the kubelet with the `--client-ca-file` flag, providing a CA bundle to verify client certificates with
- start the apiserver with `--kubelet-client-certificate` and `--kubelet-client-key` flags
- ensure the `authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1` API group is enabled in the API server
- start the kubelet with the `--authentication-token-webhook` and `--kubeconfig flags`
- the kubelet calls the `TokenReview` API on the configured API server to determine user information from bearer tokens

2. [Kubelet authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization):

- ensure the `authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` API group is enabled in the API server
- start the kubelet with the `--authorization-mode=Webhook` and the `--kubeconfig` flags
- the kubelet calls the `SubjectAccessReview` API on the configured API server to determine whether each request is authorized

3. Use the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` flag to provide the apiserver with a root certificate bundle to use to verify the kubelet's serving certificate.

More details can be found in the linked documentation.