# CIS benchmark issue for Kubernetes cluster

Tags: security, kubernetes

I'm running the **CIS kube-bench tool** on the master node and trying to resolve this error

```
[FAIL] 1.2.6 Ensure that the --kubelet-certificate-authority argument is set as appropriate (Automated).
```

I understand that I need to update the API server manifest YAML file with this flag pointing to the right CA file **--kubelet-certificate-authority** however, I'm not sure which one is the right CA Certififace for Kubelet.

These are my files in the PKI directory:-

```
apiserver-etcd-client.crt
apiserver-etcd-client.key
apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
apiserver-kubelet-client.key
apiserver.crt
apiserver.key
ca.crt
ca.key
etcd
front-proxy-ca.crt
front-proxy-ca.key
front-proxy-client.crt
front-proxy-client.key
sa.key
sa.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

3 very similar discussions on the same topic. I wont provide you all steps cause it well written in documentation and related questions on stack. Only high-level overview

1. [How Do I Properly Set --kubelet-certificate-authority apiserver parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994701/how-do-i-properly-set-kubelet-certificate-authority-apiserver-parameter)
2. [Kubernetes kubelet-certificate-authority on premise with kubespray causes certificate validation error for master node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018120/kubernetes-kubelet-certificate-authority-on-premise-with-kubespray-causes-certif)
3. [Kubernetes kubelet-certificate-authority on premise with kubespray causes certificate validation error for master node](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/6760#issuecomment-711732503)

Your actions:

- Follow the Kubernetes documentation and setup the [TLS connection between the apiserver and kubelets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#apiserver-to-kubelet).

> These connections terminate at the kubelet's HTTPS endpoint. **By
> default, the apiserver does not verify the kubelet's serving
> certificate, which makes the connection subject to man-in-the-middle
> attacks** and unsafe to run over untrusted and/or public networks.

- Enable [Kubelet authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authentication) and [Kubelet authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization)

Then, edit the API server pod specification file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on the master node and set the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` parameter to the **path to the cert file for the certificate authority**.

---

From @Matt [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025448/9929015)

- Use `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt` to sign new certificate for kubelet with valid IP SANs.
- Set `--kubelet-certificate-authority=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt` (valid CA).
- In `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` (kubelet config file) set `tlsCertFile` and `tlsPrivateKeyFile` to point to newly created kubelet `crt` and `key` files.

And from [clarifications](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/6760#issuecomment-784337506):

> Yes you have to generate certificates for kubelets and sign sign them
> the provided certificate authority located here on the master
> `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt`

Answer (score 0):

By default in Kubernetes there are 3 different Parent CA (kubernetes-ca, etcd-ca, kubernetes-front-proxy-ca). You are looking for kubernetes-ca because kubelet using kubernetes-ca, and you can check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/). kubernetes-ca default path is /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt But also you verify it via kubelet configmap  with below commands

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system $(kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system | grep kubelet  | awk '{print $1}') -o yaml | grep -i clientca
```